# Centering a sprite as div background

Tags: css, sprite, css-sprites, sprite-sheet

I have a button consisting of a sprite set as the background image of a div. The sprite sheet is arranged horizontally. Note that the source image is also being scaled down to fit the div.

```
.button {
    background: url(sprite.png);
    background-size: auto 100%;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-position: 0px 50%;
}

.play {
    background-position: 0px;
}

.pause {
    background-position: -100px;
}
```

I would like the button to shrink slightly when clicked, like so:

```
.button:active {
    background-size: auto 95%;
}
```

However, this makes the button shrink towards the left edge. **How could I centre the image, while respecting the position offset for the sprite?**

Ideally, the solution would be independent of size, so that the same style would work if the div dimensions were changed, or set dynamically. However, I'm even struggling to get the desired effect with just a manual solution such as:

```
.play:active {
    background-position: 3px 50%;
}

.pause:active {
    background-position: -97px 50%;
}
```

### Edit

Fixed some incidental mistakes in the quoted code.

Answer (score 0):

```
.button {
    background: url("sprite.png");
    background-position: center;
    background-size: auto 100%;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.button:active {
    background-size: auto 95%;
}
```

Is this working?

Comment: Er, no... I'm not sure what part of this you propose as a solution. `background-position: center` is still overridden in the classes `.play` and `.pause` - as they should be if I don't want the button to be the area in the middle of my spritesheet...

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that `src` should be `url`. That was a mistake when retyping the code here.